# Can stable magnetic field induce current?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, superconductivity

I read about a experiment conducted in 1933 by W.Meissner that follows:

Metal was put in constant magnetic field then been cooled down in order to enter superconductivity state. Then researchers discovered there is no Magnetic induction line inside the metal. Does this mean that stable magnetic field can induce current that stopped Magnetic induction line from entering the metal? If it is true, how does Maxwell's equations explain them?

Comment: please give a link to the source

Comment: I think it is called Meissner effect